# Use Different Value for searching than is displayed with Material UI's Autocomplete for React in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI's `<AutoComplete />` component.
It dictates the following structure for the options

```
const options = [
  { label: 'The Godfather', id: 1 },
  { label: 'Pulp Fiction', id: 2 },
];
// or
const options = ['The Godfather', 'Pulp Fiction'];
```

How, what I want is a string used for the search, yet another string displayed as result.
So something like

```
const options = [
  { label: 'The Godfather', toBeDisplayed: 1972 },
  { label: 'Pulp Fiction', toBeDisplayed: 1994 },
];
```

Here is [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1uzrmb?file=/demo.tsx:0-5162) to play around (from the material ui documentation)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#createfilteroptions-config-filteroptions) will solve your question. `stringify: (option) => option.title` you change option.title to option.`what_key_you_want`